# where condition to not count if some field is null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below:

```
               Table Value
-----------------------------------------
id    attribute1   attribute2   attribute3   active
232       A           null          B           Y
486      null          A           null         N
986      null         null         null         Y
509       B            C            D           N
824      null          B            C           Y
712       A            C           null         N
```

I need to get id = 232,824 and created a query like this:

```
select id 
from value 
where active = 'Y' 
and attribute1 is not null 
or attribute2 is not null 
or attribute3 is not null
```

but it's doesn't work.

and i confused **without using id in where condition**.
And i need to create where condition with that attribute and active flag, (only not get id if all attribute is null)..

Answer (score 3):

This is simple enough:

```
select count(*)
from t
where attribute1 is not null or attribute2 is not null or attribute3 is not null;
```

EDIT:

You just need correct parentheses:

```
select count(*)
from t
where active = 'Y' and
      (attribute1 is not null or attribute2 is not null or attribute3 is not null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget the brackets

```
select id from value where active = 'Y' 
and (attribute1 is not null or 
attribute2 is not null or 
attribute3 is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

another way without using OR clause could be

```
SELECT *
FROM value
WHERE active                                                                           = 'Y'
AND DECODE(attribute1,NULL,0,1) + DECODE(attribute2,NULL,0,1)+DECODE(attribute3,NULL,0,1)>1;
```

Here is the SQL fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df757/2

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question.
You want all rows where `active` equals `Y` and no attribute column contains `null`.

```
select *
from value
where active = 'Y'
   and attribute1 is not null
   and attribute2 is not null
   and attribute3 is not null
```

This returns exactly the 2 rows(Id 232 & 824) you want. You just messed up the and's with or's.

Answer (score 0):

You state you want a query that extracts id's 232 and 824 from your test data set.

Here goes:

```
select id 
  from value 
 where attribute2='B'
    or attribute3='B';
```